How to Control Swipe-Up on Home Button in Flutter App?
enter image description hereWhen I play some games on iOS, I notice that they have a way to prevent users from accidentally tapping the home button while playing. I want to apply this feature to my Flutter application. How can I do this? I would appreciate any help.
I tried many ways but without success

this is the UIKit property you need. I don't know how to access this from Flutter/Dart though

You can use GestureDetector or WillPopScope.
You can wrap your main widget with a GestureDetector to intercept swipe gestures. By doing this, you can control how your app responds to swipe actions.
dart
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.delta.dy < 0) {
      // Prevent swipe-up action
      return;
    }
  },
  child: YourMainWidget(),
);

The WillPopScope widget can be used to control the back navigation behavior. While it primarily handles back button presses, it can also help manage swipe gestures in some cases.
dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    // Return false to prevent the app from closing
    return false;
  },
  child: YourMainWidget(),
);


WillPopScope is depreciated now. You can use BackButtonListener
